# How to batch process a storing all folder names in a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking to store all the folder names in a text file.

I use this commands

1. ssh login@servername.com
2. cd /folder
3. ls > /folder/output.txt or ls | ssh ssh login@servername2.com "cat>/folder/output.txt"(Common output location)

I repeat this on another server

Essentially i want to create a script that can run from one server and store the outputs from all servers in one location.

Comment: Can you clarify where you execute command number 2 (on the local or remote system), and what command number 3 is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh` command (See `man ssh`) lets one specify a command to run remotely, e.g.

```
ssh login@server1 ls /folder >server1.txt
```

Since the redirection (`>server1.txt`) takes place on your local host, there's no need to "retrieve" the output from `server1`.

```
for srv in server1 server2 server3 ; do
    ssh login@$srv ls /folder >$srv.txt
done
```